# How to display when closed or open javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code from https://codepen.io/zeinab92/pen/xwWGWM

How can I edit the javascript so the opening times are as following:

```
Monday  6am–1am
Tuesday 6am–1am
Wednesday   6am–1am
Thursday    6am–1am
Friday  6am–1am
Saturday    8am–6pm
Sunday  10am–4pm
```

I have tried doing the following however when i visit the webpage it still says that 'We're closed' (monday) although I already set the day of the weeks and hours. I have a feeling that the else statement might be conflicting with it.

Can anyone help please

```
    var now = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

....
....
....
....
      if ((dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5) && hour >= 6 && hour <= 0) {
        hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
        timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
        timeDiv.className = 'open';
      } 

      else if ((dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 8 && hour <= 18) {
        hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
        timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
        timeDiv.className = 'open';
      } 

      else if ((dayOfWeek == 0) && hour >= 10 && hour <= 16) {
        hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
        timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
        timeDiv.className = 'open';
      } 

      else {
        if (hour == 0 || hour > 12) {
          hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
        }
        timeDiv.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re closed!';
        timeDiv.className = 'closed';
      }
    };
  ....
...
...
...
```

Comment: You should do that on the server if you can.

Comment: Is "_Monday  6am–1am_" actually Monday  6am – Tuesday 1am ..?

Comment: It'd be better to use a hash `weekday => hours_range` instead of bunch of `if`s

Comment: The code you have posted here is different from the codepen. And in the codepen, dayOfWeek = 1 for monday which means the last else block is executed.

Comment: @Teemu "Monday 6am–1am" actually Monday 6am – Tuesday 1am  is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your first if is incorrect as you are checking that hour is >= 6 and <= 0

use next one

```
if( ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(dayOfWeek) >= 0) && 
   ((hour >= 6 && hour <= 23) || hour == 0) ) { ... }
```

In following if statements you also have things like <= 18. That will also include 18:30h, everything until 18:59

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers and comments above, this should really be a server side calculation.

However, the issue lies with your code for the first if statement, particularly this section:

`hour >= 6 && hour <= 0`

It is physically impossible for the hour to be more than or equal to 6, but also less than or equal to 0, therefore it is completely ignoring that section and moving down to the final else statement.

My recommendation for this would be to change this section to:

`((hour >= && hour <= 23) || hour == 0)`